# Passing variables over several degrees of separation

Tags: python, global-variables, parameter-passing

(python) problem here which I haven't found a good workaround for.

Let's say I have a boolean Flag in a source file myfunc.py

```
# myfunc.py

bool_val = False

# Potentially change flag
if (some_condition_is_met):
    bool_val = True

# Many other function calls down the line
do_other_stuff()
```

Now, let's say that "do_other_stuff" calls a cascade of other functions, such as:

*do_other_stuff()* calls *func1()*,  which then calls *func2()*,  which then calls *func3()*... 
and eventually *importantfunc()* is called.

Now, "importantfunc" needs to know what the value of "bool_val" is

```
# importantfunc.py
if bool_val is True:
    do_something()
elif bool_val is False:
    do_something_else()
```

The problem is that my SW architecture makes it very impractical to pass the value of "bool_val" down the cascade of function calls.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get around this problem? Or something obvious I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your situation, you could put these functions in a class, store the boolean as a field at the beginning, and access it at the end.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, but unfortunately, these functions need to be in separate source files. (The functions are actually class methods in a broader obj. oriented architecture, but I left as simple functions for simplicity in defining the problem)

Comment: Are the initial assignments inside functions? If not, it should be setting a global variable, and functions will automatically use the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem you're running into calls the architecture into question, try this:

```
global bool_val = False
```